# How to use SPARQL to query local ttl file?

Tags: sparql, rdf, ttl

I'm learning how to query ttl file that I retrieve from Wikipedia.
However, I stuck on getting the correct query to show the result that I seek for an answer.

Here is the example ttl file that I used.

```
# File name : WikipediaGraph.ttl
@prefix ns1: <http://www.example.com/> .

<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abilene,_Texas> ns1:2010population "117063" ;
    ns1:2019population "123420" ;
    ns1:areaSqKm "276.4" ;
    ns1:areaSqMile "106.7" ;
    ns1:popChange "5.43" ;
    ns1:popPerSqKm "442" ;
    ns1:popPerSqMile "1146" ;
    ns1:state <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas> .
```

The sample question that I want to get an answer to listed below.

- Which state(s) has the most cities in the list? *
- Which state(s) has the most population in cities in the list? *
- Which state(s) has seen its cities in the list grow the most? *

Therefore, I stuck from the beginning as I can't get the result from the simple query.

```
import rdflib
from rdflib import Graph, URIRef, Literal, Namespace, RDF

g=rdflib.Graph()
g.parse("WikipediaGraph.ttl", format='turtle')

results = g.query("""
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX ns1: <http://www.example.com/>
    SELECT ?v
    WHERE {
    ?v rdf:type ns1:state .
    }
    ORDER BY ?NAME
""")

print('Results!')
for row in results:
    print(row)
```

Could you please advise how I should write to query the above question?

Comment: what does not work with your query? I mean, it obviously doesn't match the example data. There is no `rdf:type` triple in your data, right? Moreover, `ns1:state` is a property given that it is used in a triple `<http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abilene,_Texas> ns1:state <http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Texas> .` - so here is the problem.

Comment: Getting all cities with its state would be `SELECT ?city ?state WHERE {?city ns1:state ?state .}` - that's where you should start. The rest needs grouping and aggregate functions, etc.

Comment: @UninformedUser Thanks and sorry that I don't understand clearly about your first answer. So I have to fix the data first before I can query it right?

Comment: Oh Okay, I do get the answer based on your advice. So I will try other queries to get proper code.
'''
results = g.query("""
    PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
    PREFIX ns1: <http://www.example.com/>
    SELECT ?city ?state
    WHERE { ?city ns1:state ?state .
    }
""")
print(results)
for row in results:
    print(row)
'''

Comment: My posted query does return city and state - now it's your task to count the cities per state - grouping with aggregate function(`count`) is the way to go

Comment: Regarding your data, I was just saying that if you want to query for something being of `rdf:type`, you have to add such data to your dataset. There is basically no magic in SPARQL - i does match exactly pattern in your data. And you can't see any `rdf:type` data in your example, right?

Comment: I got it. No, there is no rdf:type in my data. So that why I can't query from rdf:type.

Comment: Thanks again for your suggestion, I will try to rest question now.